# Kubuntu bootloader overwritten by windows bootloader. Cant choose to run Kubuntu anymore!

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, multi-boot

My laptop had Kubuntu installed earlier but then I made a new installation of windows 7 ultimate. Now I cannot choose to run Kubuntu anymore as its bootloader was overwritten. How can I configure my system for dual boot ?

[I am new to Linux/ Kubuntu]

Comment: http://paranoid-engineering.blogspot.com/2008/12/how-to-restore-grub-after-windows.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boot from the Kubuntu CD

from the Terminal in Kubuntu write:

> sudo grub
>
> root (hd0,0)
>
> setup (hd0)
>
> exit

Restart and the boot menu will be back

Comment: That is assuming that the Kubuntu is installed on first hard drive and first partition on it. Otherwise the hd0 and hd0,0 parameters will have to be edited. The count starts from 0.

Comment: Don't tell me that there isn't a recovery option in Ubuntu. In OpenSuSe you just pop the CD in, boot, select recovery and you are done. No manual intervention needed. (-1, since this can actually break the PC even further if the parameters are wrong)

Comment: Thanks! Do I need to opt for "Try kubuntu" after booting with Kubuntu disk or otherwise how do I get to terminal ??

Comment: As mentioned above, the parameters might have to be adjusted to represent the HD on which Ubuntu has been installed.

Comment: @Marcos Yes you do. When you pick that option, Kubuntu form the CD should load and let you do what's needed.

Comment: As @Let_ME_Be mentioned, there might be an automatic fix when you boot from the Kubuntu CD, otherwise choose "Try Kubuntu" and follow the instructions above

Answer (score 0):

I actually took the time to research the Ubuntu grub recovery options. Please follow this wiki tutorial:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Doing this will over-write the windows boot loader, fixing one problem and creating another... I believe there was an anecdote about glass houses and stones that applies here for your comments above about lack of experts on this site...

Comment: @Kyle Uh? You need to overwrite the Windows bootloader, ok you can actually boot grub from the Windows bootloader, but that is a little overkill.